# Why am I getting an exc_bad_instruction in Sprite Kit?

Tags: swift, swift3, sprite-kit

I am getting an exc_bad_instruction here:

```
let enemy = childNode(withName: EnemyCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
```

Which is located in my didMove function in my GameScene. I didn't have this error before until I added a MenuScene(For my Menu Screen) which happens first and then transitions into my GameScene.

The error happens when I make the transition.

Comment: Most likely because of forced downcasting. Put ? Instead of ! and use if let syntax ... Seems that node with that name is not an SKSpriteNode.

Comment: what is EnemyCategoryName ?

Comment: I found out my problem. It is due to the sks file not rendering. But I don't know how to fix it. I described the problem in detail in my newest question. Please check that out if you can. Thank you!